# Network Simulator that allows defining processes to perform tasks

Tags: networking, simulation

I'm looking for a network simulator that can allow me to actually define processes for each node by writing code. I am well versed in C, CPP, Java, JavaScript, PHP & Python. So, it doesn't matter which language is supported by the simulator for writing code. I'm fine with any language.

A sample simulation that I'd like to develop would be like this:

Node 1:

- Process 1: Send predefined string periodically to Node 3
- Process 2: Update stored user_id on receiving a specific message ( HTTP Request ) from Node 3

Node 2:

- Process 1: Send random value in a range with user_id in JSON format periodically to Node 3
- Process 2: Update stored user_id on receiving a specific message ( HTTP Request ) from Node 3

Node 3: Respond to the received message ( HTTP Request ) depending on the message content

- Message 1: Send updated user_id to Node 1 & Node 2
- Message 2: Store data received from Node 1 & Node 2 in filesystem
- Message 3: Send data stored in filesystem to sender

I've so far tried to search similar functionality in NS3, GNS3, iFogSim & Cisco but haven't found out how to implement a system of this kind. Please share links for any simulator that can be used to build something like this & any related tutorials.

Thanks a lot in advance. Have a great day !!!